# fullcalendar v2 cut half First and Last Cell on backgroundEvent

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

Using fullcalendar.io v2.

How can I, using some callback and/or jquery, cut in half the first and last cell on a backgroundEvent like the attached image? Or maybe apply a different css to that cell

[image: Fullcalendar backgroundEvent manual cut]

I know that I can render an Event with time included, but I need allDay event to fill the background color of the table cell..

I tried eventRender but with no luck.. maybe because it's backgroundEvent?!

```
                eventRender: function (event, element) {
                if (event.date === event.start) element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
            }
```

Comment: inspect the live html, will see that an event `element` sits on top of another layer for the days

Comment: how can i select the first and last day of an event (backgroundEvent) to change the CSS?
I see
`<tr><td colspan="3"></td><td colspan="4" class="fc-bgevent"></td></tr>`
but it uses a colspan, not individual cells ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it with eventAfterAllRender callback.

[image]

```
eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {

jQuery.each($calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents'), function () {

var event = this;
var $start = $calendar.find('td.fc-day[data-date="' + event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '"]');
var $end = $calendar.find('td.fc-day[data-date="' + event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '"]');

if (event.rendering === 'background') {

if ($start.hasClass('fc-backgroundeventend')) {
    $start.removeClass('fc-backgroundeventend').addClass('fc-backgroundeventendstart');
    } else {
    $start.addClass('fc-backgroundeventstart'); }

for (var d = event.start.clone().add(1, 'day') ; d < event.end; d.add(1, 'day'))
{ $calendar.find('td.fc-day[data-date="' + d.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '"]').addClass('fc-backgroundevent'); }

if ($end.hasClass('fc-backgroundeventstart')) {
    $end.removeClass('fc-backgroundeventstart').addClass('fc-backgroundeventendstart');
    } else {
    $end.addClass('fc-backgroundeventend'); }

} // /event.rendering === 'background'
}); // /each

} // /eventAfterAllRender
```

and with the css classes:

```
.fc-backgroundevent {
    background-color: #ff8a8a;
}

.fc-backgroundeventendstart {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(255,138,138,1) 49%,rgba(255,138,138,1) 49%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 49%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 49%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 51%,rgba(255,138,138,1) 51%,rgba(255,138,138,1) 51%);
}

.fc-backgroundeventstart {
    background: linear-gradient(to left top, #ff8a8a 50%, #FFFFFF 50%) !important;
}

.fc-backgroundeventend {
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #ff8a8a 50%, #FFFFFF 50%) !important;
}
```

and I had to change color of the backGroundEvent to transparent:

```
.fc-bgevent {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have a live version (jsfiddle) of this example?

Comment: No, I dont have a jsfiddle example.. but it is simple to implement.

Comment: @Wilf if you need some help just ask :)

Comment: Hi, looking to achieve this with v4 or v5, any idea?